# How do I compute the surface & volume of a large amount of STL files?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, software, cad, stl

Please, how do I compute the surface & volume of a large amount of [STL files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) ?

I have **over 3000 STL files**, and I want to know their respective **volumes and surfaces**. I will use this data to be able to identify the biggest part, the one with the biggest surface, etc.

I found that the fine [Admesh](https://github.com/admesh/admesh/releases) (included in openscad, as far as I know) software that can compute the volume via command-line (powershell) and with some text editing I can get the volumes for all of these parts (needing some patience), but I didn't find any similar tool for the surface.

The best tool would output such thing as:

> `input.stl - 75.554mm2 - 45.547mm3`

I'm not sure this post is adequate in here, but anyway, thanks.

Comment: Depending on how comfortable you are with programming, calculating the surface is pretty easy. Simply sum the area of all the triangles in the file.

Comment: Well, the fact is that I am not comfortable with programming. I am learning a lot in computer science in general, but my programming skills are limited to (very) simple scripts like `$ cp -r \some\folder \some\destination\ ; shutdown`.

Not that I wouldn't like to learn about, but I don't really have the time… yet, at least.

Comment: if you can find the weight (aka filament use estimate) and the volume, can you computer surface? idk

Comment: @dandavis I don't understand what do you mean. I am searching for the **surface of the parts**, which is independent from the volume (volume and weight being proportionals, tighten by [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density)). i.e.: [these parts](https://www.netfabb.com/sites/default/files/blog/SilverStructures002.jpg) have a much higher surface over volume ratio than [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Pallo_valmiina.jpg/800px-Pallo_valmiina.jpg).

Comment: [admesh -c](https://admesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html) will give you a summary that includes volume, you colud grep for the line/value after "volume : "

Comment: @esoterik I already talked about it in my post.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **Python console of FreeCAD**. Issuing the following commands

```
FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Shape.Area
FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Shape.Volume
```

will output the area and the volume of the object, respectively.

I don't know how to access the console output from outside FreeCAD, but there is an option in FreeCAD called **Redirect internal Python output to report view** which I think is what you are looking for.

You might want to look into the Scripting documentation of FreeCAD for further instructions.

[image: Using the Python console of FreeCAD to calcaulate area and volume of an object]

Comment: I am quite sure, that Python also could be used to automate this fully, if one is good with it.

Comment: Am I wrong assuming that this would require me to import STL file to FreeCAD and process the volume/surface as described, unload the file, reload the next STL file? Would your answer implies me to do so file by file for the 3000+ files mentionned in the post?